# Watch meteor.js server bandwidth usage?

Tags: javascript, node.js, meteor

I managed to measure the bandwidth of a "simple node.js server" [using this little trick](https://gist.github.com/mekwall/4458195) but i'm not exactly sure how i could do this on a meteor instance?

Answer (score 1):

Simply

- turn your node.js script into a package
- and require it in your Meteor application ([The Meteor Chef - Using NPM Packages](https://themeteorchef.com/snippets/using-npm-packages/)

However, you should manage micro service scaling - so called "load balancing" - on the system level rather than on the application level.

Consider to use something like [Nginx](https://github.com/arunoda/meteor-up/wiki/Using-Meteor-Up-with-NginX-vhosts)

Comment: i can sort my loadbalance easily using just meteor (( :
once an instance has bandwidth over X i'll spawn another node using javascript API for digital ocean for instance and share the job queue.. i don't need to add nginx to this, yet (( :

Answer (score 0):

you could also try cluster pacakge (https://atmospherejs.com/meteorhacks/cluster) for loadbalancing and you could you use 
Kadira (http://kadira.io/) for monitoring, give it a try

Comment: i already use cluster and kadira! Thank you very much! But in my case i would need to set machines as available/not available depending on how much bandwidth node.js is using, any tips on this direction?